# I need to understand how to 'read" a cookie file. I am not a techie

Tags: google-chrome

Please help me understand, first and foremost are the following first party cookies or 3rd and what they mean, what activity occurred? Thank you very much.

```
Name:       PrefID
Content:        14-2772041597
Domain:     .match.com
path:           /
Send for        Any kind of connection
Accesible to script:    Yes
Created:        Wednesday, August 6, 2014 10;29:06 AM
Expires:        Friday, August 5, 2016 10:29:06 AM

Name:           _qca
Content:        P0-1321491634-1398204363742
Domain:     .thinkbabynames.com
path:           /
Send for        Any kind of connection
Accesible to script:    Yes
Created:        Tuesday, April 22, 2014 6:06:03PM
Expires:        Thursday, October 22, 2015 2:49:12 PM
```

This was the cookie history on 8/2/14.

```
Name:       XGIR
Content:        oVe3sa3+oCMM6XAqesACXt|8CtBa22|Qi|rDDJu|f5|JJD|SIY|rDD|
Domain:     media.match.com
path:           /
Send for        Any kind of connection
Accesible to script:    Yes
Created:        Tuesday July 29, 2014 8:36:04AM
Expires:        When the browsing session ends
```

If it expires when the browsing session ends, why was it present on the 8/2/14 cookie list?

```
Name:       RUN_ID
Content:        207c130428024b3eb9b5781b
Domain:     match.rundsp.com
path:           /
Send for        Any kind of connection
Accesible to script:    Yes
Created:        Saturday, August 2, 2014 11:07:57 AM
Expires:        Friday, October 31, 2014 11:07:57 AM
```

Please help my understand how to read all this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies can contain anything a website wants to include, in any format or encoding it chooses, so in general it is not possible to discover the "meaning" of a cookie by looking at the data it contains unless you are privy to the scheme the website is using.

Likewise, it is not possible to tell whether a cookie is "third party" or not merely by looking at it: the exact same cookie can be "first party" or "third party" depending on the browsing context.

Expired cookies, including session cookies from a previous session, are not necessarily deleted from the browser's cookie store immediately upon expiration, but should not be sent
in subsequent requests made to the website that issued them.

Answer (score 0):

> Please help my understand how to read all this

I've found a good expaination [here](http://www.webopedia.com/DidYouKnow/Internet/all_about_cookies.asp).

> If it expires when the browsing session ends, why was it present on the 8/2/14 cookie list?

Thre are two types of cookies:

- **session cookie**

Also called a transient cookie, a cookie that is erased when you close the Web browser. The session cookie is stored in temporary memory and is not retained after the browser is closed. Session cookies do not collect information from your computer. They typically will store information in the form of a session identification that does not personally identify the user.

- **persistent cookie**

Also called a permanent cookie, or a stored cookie, a cookie that is **stored on your hard drive until it expires** (persistent cookies are set with expiration dates) or until you delete the cookie. Persistent cookies are used to collect identifying information about the user, such as Web surfing behavior or user preferences for a specific Web site.

Comment: The description of session cookies above is not accurate for browsers that can save and restore browsing sessions. In that case session cookies can be stored on disk (and reloaded later) because the "session" effectively does not end when the browser is closed.

Comment: May be not, OK, but it is helpful to understand the basics of how cookies work